# Query for showing whole records where a particular field is entered twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem here in that I don't know how to execute this S Q L query as I am not sure of the correct syntax...

I am trying to select all records from a record set (populated by a table), where a particular field is entered twice...
please what query should i use to get all records which showing double records in a field.

Comment: It would help to know the table structure and what field are you expecting duplicate data in.

Comment: sample data + expected resultset + what did you try?

Comment: **group by** all the other fields, **having** count > 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select columnname,count(*) as cnt
from dbo.table
group by columnname
having count(*) > 1
```

this gives you the rows which has duplicates in the column " columnname" . edit to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
SELECT "YourFieldName(s)", COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
FROM "YourTableName"
GROUP BY "YourFieldName(s)"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

"YourFieldName(s)" can be multiple columns if that is what you are checking duplicates on.